# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\IntlDateFormatter' not found

Tags: php, date, laravel, persian, persian-calendar

I develop this code to view Tehran time and date with php:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);

    echo "Date: " . $fmt->format(time()) . "\n";
```

this code works fine but, I want to use it in a function in my controller in Laravel.

Route:

```
Route::get('/date', [
'as' => 'date', 'uses' => 'HomeController@date'
]);
```

Controller :

```
public function date() {
    $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);

    echo "Date: " . $fmt->format(time()) . "\n";
}
```

And the result is :

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\IntlDateFormatter' not found

I know that there is not IntlDateFormatter class in Laravel but I except that use php class here. what is my mistake?

Comment: add more code and explanation please

Comment: Try to use as `\IntlDateFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for response, I forgotted to add

> use IntlDateFormatter;

So the not found error solved by adding that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the namespace your Class lies in.

Remember that the `app\`folder is PSR-4 loaded, so if for example your class is defined in a file called IntlDateFormatter.php, you need to put this file somewhere in your `app\`. Then in your controller you import the class:

```
// in your controller 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\{your class location}\IntlDateFormatter;
```

Comment: it is a standard class of php and I used without app\{class name}, and it works fine, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using custom classes in Laravel:

```
<?php
namespace YourProject\Services;
class IntlDateFormatter{
  public static function dateFormat(){
    /*Do your date formatting here and return desired result*/
  }
}
```

I asume you save this file inside app directory.
Next in config/app.php inside aliases array, add

```
'IntlDateFormatter'     => Artisanian\Services\IntlDateFormatter::class,
```

This way you can easily call `dateFormat` function as follow:

```
\IntlDateFormatter::dateFormat();
```

Either in your controller or in your view.

I hope this help.

Good luck.